# Building a SQL segment using a CASE in the WHERE

Tags: case

Is it possible to build sql parts within a case

For example I have a database where I have a statement

```
    where p.budget_key = l.Budget_key 
      and p.amount_finished > 0 
      and p.amount_finished > (select isnull(sum(dline_amount),0) from         trimergo.delivery_line where dline_planningid = p.planning_key)
```

now what i want is like an if statement

```
    AND CASE WHEN p.type_name = 'Service' THEN and p.amount_finished > 0
    ELSE p.amount_finished < 0
```

Or something along these lines. Building actually sql segments
Is this possible?

This is for MS Server 2012 version.

after first awnser. my currect syntax is

```
    AND (CASE WHEN p.type_name <> 'Service' THEN p.amount_finished END ) > 0
    AND (CASE WHEN p.type_name <> 'Service' THEN p.amount_finished END ) > (select isnull(sum(dline_amount),0) from trimergo.delivery_line where dline_planningid = p.planning_key)
    AND (CASE WHEN p.type_name = 'Service' THEN p.status END ) > '150-01'
```

the point now remains. that if the type_name = 'Service' then it only needs to check the p.status part and now the amount parts. so is it possible to like "choose" which AND statement he needs to use for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Case is possible in Where clause.Syntax of Case is wrong in your example,

```
AND (CASE WHEN p.type_name = 'Service' THEN  p.amount_finished 
ELSE 0 End) = @someVariable
```